# SQL Server trigger on a procedure failing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I am trying to trigger a stored procedure to take the inserted values into my stored procedure as parameters and it is not letting me.

My table flow goes like this: a patient's history information will be inserted (`HISTORY_APPOINTMENTS`) and if at the time the patient has a column value of `HasSuicidalThoughts = 'Y'` I want the trigger to send the inserted patients information into a table I created called `SuicideWatchLog`.

First I created the table:

```
/* Table Creation for SuicideWatch Log*/
CREATE TABLE SuicideWatchLog
(
    logNum integer IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PatientStudy# integer FOREIGN KEY References Patients(PatientStudy#),
    PatientName varchar(20),
    [Date] date,
    Dr# integer FOREIGN KEY References DOCTORS(Dr#),
    DaysinStudy integer
)
```

Next I created the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddSuicideWatch
    @PatientStudy# integer,
    @PatientName varchar(20),
    @Date date,
    @Dr# integer,
    @DaysinStudy integer
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SuicideWatchLog(PatientStudy#, Date, Dr#)
        (SELECT PatientStudy#, ApptDate, Dr#
         FROM APPOINTMENTS
         WHERE @PatientStudy# = PatientStudy#
           AND @Date = ApptDate
           AND @Dr# = Dr#)

    INSERT INTO SuicideWatchLog(PatientName, DaysinStudy)
        (SELECT PatientFName, datediff(day,StudyStartDate,getdate())
         FROM PATIENTS
         WHERE @PatientName = PatientFName
           AND @DaysinStudy = datediff(day,StudyStartDate,getdate()))
END
```

Finally I created the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SuicidalPatient
ON HISTORY_APPOINTMENT
AFTER INSERT
AS
    EXEC AddSuicideWatch(
        SELECT (I.PatientStudy#, P.PatientFName, A.ApptDate,  
        FROM INSERTED I
        JOIN APPOINTMENTS A ON I.Appt# = A.Appt#
        JOIN PATIENTS P ON I.PatientStudy# = P.PatientStudy#)
```

I expected this to allow me to send the inserted values into the stored procedure to trigger the creation of the log, but instead I am getting an error that is telling me my parameters aren't being found.

Is this an issue with the select statement, or is it a problem with the procedure itself?

Comment: Your procedure inserts two row which presumably should be one. Then you cannot pass a query to a procedure and your parenthesis aren't balanced in the trigger. And most importantly it's not advisable to materialize values (or records) that can be deduced by other values (or records) as this comes with high risk of ending in inconsistencies. Create a view instead.

Comment: `
 CREATE PROCEDURE AddSuicideWatch2
 @PatientStudy# integer,
 @PatientName varchar(20),
 @Date date,
 @Dr# integer,
 @DaysinStudy integer
 AS
 BEGIN
 INSERT into SuicideWatchLog(PatientStudy#,PatientName,Date,Dr#,DaysinStudy)
  SELECT A.PatientStudy#, P.PatientFName, A.ApptDate, A.Dr#, DS.[Days In Study]
   FROM APPOINTMENTS A join PATIENTS P
    ON A.PatientStudy# = P.PatientStudy#
    join DaysInStudy DS
    ON DS.PatientStudy# = P.PatientStudy#
 END`

Answer (score 2):

> Is this an issue with the select statement, or is it a problem with the procedure itself?

Your stored procedure accepts scalar parameters.  You can't pass a whole resultset to it.  You can:

1) Integrate the INSERTs directly into the trigger body, eliminating the stored procedure.

2) Open a cursor over the query in the trigger, and loop through the rows, calling the stored procedure fore each one.

3) Declare a User-Defined Table Type matching the query result rows, declare and load an instance of the table type in the trigger body, and change the stored procedure to accept a Table-Valued Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you cant pass table to sp , but i know 2 ways for that :
1- use user defined type like that :

```
create type NewTable AS table (PatientStudy# int, PatientFName nvarchar(max), ApptDate date)
```

and the insert into NewTable Then call sp

```
declare @TempTable NewTable
insert into  @TempTable(PatientStudy# , PatientFName , ApptDate)
select I.PatientStudy#, P.PatientFName, A.ApptDate,  
        FROM INSERTED I
        JOIN APPOINTMENTS A ON I.Appt# = A.Appt#
        JOIN PATIENTS P ON I.PatientStudy# = P.PatientStudy#

EXEC AddSuicideWatch( @TempTable)
```

and of course you should edit your SP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddSuicideWatch
    @Table NewTable
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SuicideWatchLog(PatientStudy#, Date, Dr#)
        SELECT PatientStudy#, ApptDate, Dr#
         FROM APPOINTMENTS A join @Table T ON
           A.PatientStudy# = T.PatientStudy#
           A.Date = T.ApptDate
           A.Dr# = D.Dr#

    INSERT INTO SuicideWatchLog(PatientName, DaysinStudy)
        (SELECT PatientFName, datediff(day,StudyStartDate,getdate())
         FROM PATIENTS P join @Table T ON
         T.PatientName = P.PatientFName
           AND A.DaysinStudy = datediff(day,StudyStartDate,getdate()))
END
```

And the seccond way : just pass the primary key to sp and handle other things in sp